# Ansible to include hosts IPs in template?

Tags: hosts, ansible

I have several IPs in my Ansible hosts file and would like to have it listed in the file that will be copied to each of these hosts. Say, this hosts are 1.1.1.1, 1.1.2.3 etc, and the is file on each of the hosts named `list.txt` should contain the following:

`All hosts in the group are: 1.1.1.1, 1.1.2.3`

I do understand I can copy file with static content or I can iterate over vars set separately but how to iterate over host list entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"How to iterate over host list entries?"*

A: There are 2 standard options. Either [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) `ansible_play_hosts_all` or `groups`. For example, with the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
10.1.0.51
10.1.0.52
10.1.0.53
```

both templates

```
shell> cat list1.txt.j2 
All hosts in the group are: 
{%- for host in ansible_play_hosts_all -%}
{{ host }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}

shell> cat list2.txt.j2 
All hosts in the group are: 
{%- for host in groups.all -%}
{{ host }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: list1.txt.j2
        dest: /tmp/list.txt
```

give on all remote hosts

```bsh
shell> cat /tmp/list.txt
All hosts in the group are:10.1.0.51, 10.1.0.52, 10.1.0.53
```